# Sharepoint 2013 Installation & Configuration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I am learning Sharepoint. I have deployed and configured SP2013 on single machine. Now I was trying to deploy SP 2013 in a small farm. My requirement is to separate the SP and its on different machine. 
For this I have taken 2 application server and one DB server. In one application server I installed SP, created farm and configured most of the farm services except search. Now I moved to another machine and installed SP, joined this machine with the existing farm, after SP installation, I then had the manage services screen where all the checkboxes were disabled except search and now I had the confusion.
my confusion was, if I will select the search service then it will be configured on the main machine then how to deploy search on this machine.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have joined the other server (Web Server) to SharePoint installed server (App Server), so Search Service will be configured on App Server. Now if you want to share the services across the Farms, below is the list of Service applications that can be shared:

1. Business Data Connectivity
2. Machine Translation
3. Managed Metadata
4. User Profile
5. Search
6. Secure Store

[Reference Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621100(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: What if, I want to install and configure the search on different server (Web Server), I don't want to deploy the search om Sharepoint Installed server (App Server).

Comment: it would be a different server then. i think new App Server in the farm with separate Central Admin and only Search Service Configured. you can do it that way.

Comment: Got it. By this way I think I just need to change the search topology to access the content of 1st SP server.

Comment: yes since it would be in same farm. so you would be able to access the content from 1st server.